# How can I use chain and filter with multiple parameters for the filter?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to write a function to narrow down a list based on a date part.
The libraries I'm using for this are underscore.js and moment.js.

Here's what I have so far.

```
var data = [{adate: "2015-09-10T00:00:00-04:00", numUnits: 0}, {adate: "2015-09-11T00:00:00-04:00", numUnits: 2}];

//used in function below
function filterByCurrentDatePart(item, datePart) {
    console.log(item);
    console.log(datePart);
    return moment().isSame(item.adate, datePart);
};

//this is the function I call.
function filterListByCurrentDatePart(inputData, datePartType) {
    return _.chain(inputData)
        .filter(filterByCurrentDatePart(datePartType))
        .value();
};
```

The problem is that datePartType is being put in as the first parameter.  Not surprising in javascript but I thought the chain function would make that implicit.

How can I get it to work using two functions?  Or do I have to combine them and use a variable at the top?

Comment: reverse the formal params in filterByCurrentDatePart(), then use `.filter(filterByCurrentDatePart.bind(null, datePartType))` in filterListByCurrentDatePart()

Comment: @dandavis This works!  Can you repost it as the answer so I can give credit?

Answer (score 0):

```js
//this is the function I call.
function filterListByCurrentDatePart(inputData, datePartType) {
  var now = moment(); //Cache it for performance reasons
  return _.chain(inputData)
    .filter(function(item) {
      return now.isSame(item.adate, datePartType)
    })
    .value();
};

var data = [{
  adate: "2015-09-10T00:00:00-04:00",
  numUnits: 0
}, {
  adate: "2015-09-19T00:00:00-04:00",
  numUnits: 2
}];

console.log(filterListByCurrentDatePart(data, 'd'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
```